# Wordpress display:none;

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

For a webshop I would like to show confetti on the checkout page. I found a plugin and its working correctly. The only problem is that the confetti is showing on every page. So far I found out that adding display:none !important; will "remove" the confetti. Is there a way to overrule display:none !important; for the checkout page?

Thank you for helping

Comment: You can assign the confetti styles to a unique class and have that class only exist on the checkout page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have an example how to assign a new class to an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice to initialize the plugin accross the whole site and then disable it to re-enable it on a specific page, you'd be better off initiating the plugin on the checkout page only.

To achieve what you're asking though, you should display:none !important; in your css, and below that you should do the following

```
.woocommerce-checkout .CONFETTICLASS { display: block !important; }
```